# How to link libcurl as Library Static in CodeBlocks (C++)

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks

Since some days Im trying to link correctly curl library in my project.
I can execute it without problem but when I try run it in other computer I have many missing DLL's errors.
[DLL Missing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQixa.png)

I linked .lib curl files to project but it persists.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You need to copy that dll along with your program or find a static build of curl

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: Probably the same place you got the shared library from